# set up authentication flow correctly in Flask app

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on integrating OAuth 2.0 into my Python Flask application, and I'm encountering some issues. I've followed the documentation for the OAuth provider I'm using, but I'm not sure if I've set up the authentication flow correctly in my Flask app. When I try to authenticate, I'm getting an error related to token retrieval.

i am confused...what i want to get is something different and which i am getting makes me think of something else. So anyone please tell me how to solve this with different approaches

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.